# Cannot view logon trigger

Tags: sql-server

I want to view my logon trigger and alter it, but I cannot seem to find it. When I create a stored procedure, I can always find the procedure in Database->Programability->Stored Procedures, right click the name of my procedure and click modify. However, when I go to Server Objects->Triggers and I right click on my trigger, there isn't an option for modifying it. What am I supposed to do to modify it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click > Script Server Trigger As > DROP and Create To > New Query Editor Window